# Non-uniform axis ticks using Show [p1, p2, PlotRange -> All] in Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying show a series of plots in the same figure using Mathematica 8 with Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> All], but the y axis label (ranging from log 0.5 to log 1.5) appears non-uniform. How can I correct the axis label to be uniform?

I've included an example with two plots (dataPlot3 and dataPlot4), but I am trying to show more in the same figure.

[image: example]

Comment: I'm certain you'll get a better response at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

`Show` uses the options from the first graphic specified, including `PlotRange` and `Ticks`.  You can specify an explicit `PlotRange` in the creation of the first plot that encompasses the range of both data sets and appropriate ticks will be generated to cover it:

```
d1 = Table[x^2, {x, 50}];
d2 = Table[50 + x^3, {x, 50}];

p1 = ListLogLogPlot[d1, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {1, 200000}]

p2 = ListLogLogPlot[d2, PlotStyle -> Black]

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, adding an explicit PlotRange helped, but I am wondering if there is another way since I will not necessarily know ahead of time the ranges of all the plots.